# Excel has comments & notes. Need to Power Query combine with notes & comments

Tags: excel, powerquery

My client has 711 excel files that we are moving to an Access database.  One column has either notes or comments attached.

Is there a way to have them transfer "as is" if I combine in Power Query?

I can (and know how to) copy them into cells, but that would mean actually touching all 711 files.

Thank you

[Example of notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpZ1f.png)

Researched and looked at Transform in Power Query to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to read notes in powerquery. Best bet is to run VBA function against the cells prior to running the powerquery.

```
Function extract(cell As Range)
    extract= cell.Comment.Text
End Function
```

You can wrap that in an overall VBA to read and pre-preprocess all the files

Comment: Thanks (I was afraid of that)...  When you say "wrap", I need to do this file to file, correct?

Comment: yes, file by file.  Unless you go through some process of unzipping each XLSX file somehow programmatically and extracting it that way

Comment: Thank you again @horseyride....  My pragmatic skills aren't up to that challenge, it ultimately it would be faster to go file by file (and normalize the data as I go).